# Router does no connect to RPi 4 after restart

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I shutdown the Pi running raspberian 64 lite with `poweroff` many times before and restarted it by un- and replugging without problems. After following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMW1Zi8MSas
tutorial, after restart, it does not connect to the router anymore, only after rewriting the OS image to the disk. Could it have something to do with the edits made? These are creating a directory
`mkdir /media/name`
and inserting a line in fstab
`/dev/partitionname  ext4 defaults,uid=1000,guid=1000,dmask=002,fmask=113,rw 0 0`

Restarting the router does not help...

Comment: watch the video again - take note of what's on the screen at the 4:43 mark, including the red text that pops up

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The guid/gid seems to have caused the problem, thx @Jaromanda X